# Building a json stub using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I am try to build a `json` using a factory, but when i try to `build` it's empty.

Below is `Factory` class.

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :account do |f|
        f.name {Faker::Name.name}
        f.description {Faker::Name.description}     
    end

    factory :accjson, class:Hash do
        "@type" "accountResource"
        "createdAt" "2014-08-07T14:31:58"
        "createdBy" "2"        
        "disabled"  "false"        
    end 
end
```

Below is how i am trying to build.

```
hashed_response = FactoryGirl.build(:accjson)        
expect(account.to_json).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);
```

But my `hashed_response` always seems to be empty `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using FactoryGirl to create a json is like using space shuttle to peel the pineapple. You'll do that after you try hard enough, but it is not what shuttle has been created for.

If you are reusing this hash structure in your test, store it within yaml file and create some helper methods to read it (you can place them within spec/spec_helpers).

### Reason why your code doesn't work:

FactoryGirl is using `method_missing` magic to assign values. In your code, you are not trying to execute any methods, as you are just listing strings, so the `method_missing` magic is not triggered.

### Way to do this with FactoryGirl (read the top paragraph!):

For completeness, there is a way to do this with FG, however is not very pretty:

```
factory :accjson, class: OpenStruct do
  send :'@type', "accountResource"
  createdAt "2014-08-07T14:31:58"
  createdBy "2"        
  disabled  "false"        
end

hashed_response = FactoryGirl.build(:accjson).marshal_dump.to_json
```

Comment: pastie.org/9455888 why is the API response different from the stub which i am creating.

Comment: @UnderTaker - How did you got those values. One is escaped, the other one is not.

Comment: First one is the json stub created via Factorygirl and other one is my API response.

Comment: I disagree with this philosophy, especially since Activerecord is less used. This means, for instance, if you used MongoId you would not be able to use fixtures and would have to use FactoryGirl for a simple json.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this using the `hashie` gem.

My factories then look like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :some_factory_name, class: Hashie::Mash do
    skip_create
    attribute1 { value }
    attribute2 { "test" }
    sequence(:attribute3) { |n| "AttributeValue#{n}" }
  end
end
```

This has worked well for me as it behaves almost exactly like a Hash but with the convenience of a factory and the simplicity of getting and setting attributes on a `Struct`.